# Problems with modules in Angular

Tags: angular

Everything was working fine until I started adding Components in the app.module. I have 2 folders, a backend which connects to the database (Mongodb) and a frontend to view the project. When I run the backend, it connects but when I run the front end, it gives me this error:

```
"ERROR in ../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/index.d.ts(1,47): error TS2307: 
Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/src/jwt.interceptor.d.ts(1,70): error 
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'.
../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/src/jwt.interceptor.d.ts(3,28): error 
TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/internal/Observable'.
../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/src/jwtoptions.token.d.ts(1,32): error 
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'."
```

My code is below.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import {MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';


import {BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';

import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { MessageComponent } from './messages/message.component';
import { AboutusComponent } from './aboutus/aboutus.component';
import {AddnewsComponent} from './addnews/addnews.component';
import {NewsListComponent} from './newslist/newslist.component';
import {ViewComponent} from './view/view.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, MessageComponent, RegisterComponent, LoginComponent,AboutusComponent,AddnewsComponent,NewsListComponent,ViewComponent
 ],
imports: [
  BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,  MatButtonModule, MatInputModule, MatToolbarModule,  BrowserAnimationsModule,
 NoopAnimationsModule, MatListModule, RouterModule.forRoot(
   [
    {path: 'addnews', component:AddnewsComponent},
    {path: 'aboutus', component: AboutusComponent},
    {path: 'newslist',component: NewsListComponent},
    {path: 'view', component: ViewComponent},
    {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
   {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
   {path: 'messages', component: MessageComponent} 
  ]
)
],
providers: [ApiService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 } )
 export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what dependencies have been added to the components. Also, are you importing the angular common module required by @auth0/angular-jwt? [It's peer dependencies](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/master/package.json) require angular common-